# Unable to plot after keras `fit` called

Tags: r, keras, r-markdown, knitr

After keras fit is called, although with interactive metrics turned off by argument, I can not output plots to knitr generated HTML anymore.

I've tried `dev.off()` after keras `fit` call with and without `plot.new()`, as well as various combinations of `dev.flush()`, `dev.new()` etc.

I want calls to `ggplot()` produce plots, but instead I get errors such as `replayPlot(x): invalid graphics state` without running `dev.off()` after keras fit, and just no plot rendered in html output if I run `dev.off()` & `plot.new()`.

Comment: Have your read [ask] and [MCVE]?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you please open an issue in https://github.com/rstudio/keras/issues and attach a document where this is happening?